# Android private fields naming guidelines are ok?

Tags: android, coding-style, field, private

Here http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions it is stated that :

> Field Names
>
> - Non-public, non-static field names start with m.
> - Static field names start with s.
> - Other fields start with a lower case letter.
> - Public static final fields (constants) are ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES.

It also states that :

> The rules below are not guidelines or recommendations, but strict rules. You may not disregard the rules we list below except as approved on a need-to-use basis.

I don't like the "m" convention before private or package fields in a class. I really find this uninspired... I mean, if we try to apply good designs, the low coupling of the classes implies having few public fields. actually, in my programs I usually have no public fields, even when I need some I use getters and setters...

So, why should I be forced to have almost all my fields in the program with an "m" in front of them? wouldn't be easier to have the few public fields, if there are any, with some "g" in front or something? or just use setters and getters as beans suggest?
this really makes my code harder to read....

Also, following these guidelines, local temp variables used in the methods have no restriction so they could easily be mistaken for public global fields (also without restriction)... this also I find to be wrong, as it is a probable source of mistakes...
I understand to have a way of differentiating from fields, but private/protected member fields are the most used in an application, they shouldn't be less "readable".

What do you think? Should I follow the guidelines?

Comment: One of the reasons prefixes like this are often mandated is to prevent hiding the member fields. For example you often have a parameter to a constructor or setter method that is the same name as the member field if you don't have any prefixes. In such cases you then have to access the member field using "this." in front of it whenever it is hidden. Programmers occasionally forget the "this.", which leads to bugs. A prefix on public fields isn't as useful because there is no need for a setter on a public field anyway.

Comment: i actually prefer the m_ prefix on private fields because it makes your class methods easier to read. These conventions are used because code is read more than its written... I think thats in Code Complete somwhere?...

Comment: i agree with you.. i dont like the "m" convention and i am happily not using it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those coding guidelines are for the Android Open Source Project which is the core Android Platform. You have to follow these guidelines if you want any of your code to be accepted into the core platform. You can do what ever you want in your own applications.
With regards to the guidelines themselves I think they are very reasonable and similar to many standards used in commercial applications. Generally you want to use getters and setters for public field access and you don't want to have global public variables. Only global public constants are ok.
So the short answer is follow them for the Open Source project, decide to follow them in you app.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to getters\setters, it is actually recommended to not use them in Android.

I found this on the "*Designing for Performance*" page (section: **Avoid Internal Getters/Setters**): http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

Bottom line, they infer that instance field lookups are more efficient than Virtual method calls (due to optimizations in the JIT).

I think I will continue to use getters\setters in my code, but this might be an easy way to improve performance (especially for apps that do a lot of data manipulation).

Comment: You have to use setter/getters to access a private field of an object of another class. However, you should limit use of these methods internally. Internally, why would you use 'name = getName()', accessing the variable directly is more efficient (name = mName)